# Magento 2 My Orders->Order Shipments->Track this shipment results in Invalid method error

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, methods

(magento 2.0.10)  My `Orders->Order Shipments->Track this shipment`->after click.

```
Invalid method Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::formatDeliveryDateTime(Array
(
    [0] => 2016-11-22
    [1] => 13:20:00
)
)
0 /usr/local/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/details.phtml(80): Magento\Framework\DataObject->__call('formatDeliveryD...', Array)
1 /usr/local/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/usr/local/ngin...')
2 /usr/local/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template), '/usr/local/ngin...', Array)
3 /usr/local/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/usr/local/ngin...')
4 /usr/local/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(657): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
5 /usr/local/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
```

---

Can you help me?
I am a beginner(Green hand), please give me answer in detail.

Thanks.

Comment: were there any customization's made in the shipping module?

Comment: Tracking XML URL  :https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track

Comment: could you give me  the configure? about UPS shipping methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Magento 2 bug.

If you look for function **formatDeliveryDateTime** inside file *vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/details.phtml* whose block is *\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template*

Use below block function

```
$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking\Popup');
```

Replace :

```
echo $block->formatDeliveryDateTime($track->getDeliverydate(), $track->getDeliverytime());
```

By

```
echo $blockObj->formatDeliveryDateTime($track->getDeliverydate(), $track->getDeliverytime());
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't access the block for some reason.  In a pinch, you could try accessing the class directly.

In vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/details.phtml, around line 80:

`<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->formatDeliveryDateTime($track->getDeliverydate(), $track->getDeliverytime()); ?>`

Replace with:

`<?php /* @noEscape */ echo \Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking::formatDeliveryDateTime($track->getDeliverydate(), $track->getDeliverytime()); ?>`

This is NOT the ideal solution here but should make it work until you figure it out.

Comment: class is wrong . use - Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking\Popup